# Why does Trump's response to Floyd George protests highlight second amendment rights?

Tags: donald-trump, second-amendment

In the linked [video](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/world-us-canada-52876499?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=twitter&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=5ed5d6c39789ad0655eceed1%26Reporter%3A%20%27No%20warnings%20given%20before%20tear%20gas%27%262020-06-02T04%3A39%3A24.498Z&ns_fee=0&pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:d0149350-4352-403d-83ba-e1ce2568b774&pinned_post_asset_id=5ed5d6c39789ad0655eceed1&pinned_post_type=share) at around 35 seconds, we have a segment from Trump's speech at the White House before his walk to St John's Church announcing the presidential response to the Floyd George protests.

Specifically in this speech Trump says;

> ...to protect the rights of all law-abiding Americans including your second amendment rights

Why is the right to bear arms specifically highlighted in this speech?

Comment: This is a question about someone's internal motivations.

Comment: @DanScally really? A major scripted speech with prepared remarks is based on internal motivations? While the segment I've pulled is short, it's not an off the cuff remark or a late night tweet, or even the response to an unexpected question. The content of the speech is (presumably) constructed with some care and put together by a team of people to send a specific and clear message.

Comment: @Jontia Yes, and political speechwriters usually don't go public and explain the speeches they wrote. So we can only guess what that remark meant. And just guessing isn't what we do on this website.